# initializing char* a = new char[size] does not work

Tags: c++

I have a problem about initializing `char* a = new char[size]`. Here is my code.

```
class Practice
{
public:
    Practice(const char* a);
    ~Practice();

    const char* getString() const;

private:
    char* mString;
    int mSize;

};
```

```
#include "Practice.h"

Practice::Practice(const char * a)
    :mSize(0)
    ,mString(nullptr)
{
    while (a[mSize] != '\0')
    {
        mSize++;
    }

    mString = new char[mSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < mSize; i++)
    {
        mString[i] = a[i];
    }

}

Practice::~Practice()
{
    delete[] mString;
}

const char* Practice::getString() const
{
    return mString;
}

int main()
{
    Practice p("Hello");

    std::cout << p.getString() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I expected the result is `Hello`.

But the result was like `Hello²²²²▌▌▌▌▌▌▌■a%{▌`.

I thought I initialized the `mString` member variable through `mString = new char[mSize]`. But it was not working the way I thought.

Can anybody enlighten me what's wrong with my code and fix it?

Comment: All `std::cout` sees is a `char *`.  There is no size information.

Comment: Your `getString` function doesn't return a string, just a pointer to a bunch of characters.

Comment: Why is this question tagged c++11 and c++17? I don't see anything related to C++11 or C++17.

Comment: Thanks a lot. now I get it and fix it. And you're right, Mr. Henze, so I deleted C ++11 and C++ 17.

Comment: @WernerHenze the code mentions `nullptr`, which was added in C++11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not null-terminating your `mString` data, but it is expecting to be null-terminated when you pass it to `std::cout`. Without that terminator, `std::cout` reads into surrounding memory until it encounters a random null byte (or crashes with a read access error). That is why you are seeing `std::cout` output random garbage after your data.

You are also not following the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), as you are missing a default constructor, copy and move constructors, and copy and move assignment operators.

Try this:

```
class Practice
{
public:
    Practice(const char* a = nullptr);
    Practice(const Practice &src);
    Practice(Practice &&src);
    ~Practice();

    Practice& operator=(Practice src);

    const char* getString() const;

private:
    char* mString;
    int mSize;
};
```

```
#include "Practice.h"
#include <utility>

Practice::Practice(const char * a)
    : mSize(0)
    , mString(nullptr)
{
    if (a)
    {
        while (a[mSize] != '\0')
        {
            ++mSize;
        }
    }

    mString = new char[mSize + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < mSize; ++i)
    {
        mString[i] = a[i];
    }

    mString[mSize] = '\0';
}

Practice::Practice(const Practice &src)
    : mSize(src.mSize)
    , mString(nullptr)
{
    mString = new char[mSize + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < mSize; ++i)
    {
        mString[i] = src.mString[i];
    }

    mString[mSize] = '\0';
}

Practice::Practice(Practice &&src)
    : mSize(src.mSize)
    , mString(src.mString)
{
    src.mString = nullptr;
    src.mSize = 0;
}

Practice::~Practice()
{
    delete[] mString;
}

Practice& Practice::operator=(Practice src)
{
    std::swap(mString, src.mString);
    std::swap(mSize, src.mSize);
    return *this;
}

const char* Practice::getString() const
{
    return mString;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Practice.h" 

int main()
{
    Practice p("Hello");

    std::cout << p.getString() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now I get it. Also, rule of 3/5/0  is very informative to me. I read it and tried the code you wrote.

Answer (score 5):

`mString` is not NUL-terminated.

Answer (score 1):

Your're checking `a` constructor parameter for `\0`. But you are not allocating `mString` to put the same `\0` there, and don't copy `\0` from `a`.

So, resulting `mString` is not properly NULL-terminated and it would be read beyond end.

Reading beyond end of allocated is undefined behavior. In particular case, it is likely that either `mString` would output until some accidental zero, or crash would occur.

Comment: Thank you. Your tip leads me to right the wrong code.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> while (a[mSize] != '\0')
> {
>     mSize++;
> }
> ```

This sets `mSize` equal to the length of `a`, excluding the terminating `'\0'`.  You should include the terminator in your copy:

```
while (a[mSize++])
{
}
```

or simply:

```
mSize = strlen(a) + 1;
```